# Azure app-service non-www to www redirect rule to ignore the cdn domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, web-config, redirect

The redirect rule below of *non-www* to *www.sitedomain.com* works, but the exemption clause for the CDN domain requests (*add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cdnprefix.azureedge.net" negate="true"*) are ignored and the cdn requests redirect as well to www.sitedomain.com. Can you help me modify the rewrite section(s) to solve that?

```
<rule name="Redirect non-www to www.sitedomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <!-- domain is not canonical  -->
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" ignoreCase="true" pattern="^sitedomain\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.sitedomain\.com$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cdnprefix\.azureedge\.net" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sitedomain.com{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Together with the effective HTTP -> httpS redirect rule (split up to simplify solution for CDN exemption rule), it looks like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect non-www to www.sitedomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <!-- domain is not canonical  -->
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" ignoreCase="true" pattern="^sitedomain\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.sitedomain\.com$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cdnprefix\.azureedge\.net" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sitedomain.com{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

For canonical domain,you only need this rule

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.\sitedomain\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sitedomain.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

Then You can add the next section for CDN

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cdnprefix\.azureedge\.net" negate="true" />
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Tried it and there's no improvement. The canonical rule works but the cdn resources redirect to the site domain **cdnprefix.azureedge.net/**_path2resource_ ->  **www.sitedomain.com/**_path2resource_

Comment: Here's the rule I have added and it works fine for me.Tested in my local  <rule name="Redirect non-www to www.sitedomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.sitedomain\.com$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cdnprefix\.azureedge\.net" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sitedomain.com{HTTP_URL}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

Comment: Since you have given the Permanent redirect,could you please remove the browser cache completely and try again.

Comment: your modified answer is a bit off on the last line it should be "www.sitedomain.com{HTTP_URL} instead of "sitedomain.com. Anyway, I tried with a different browser and using the dev tools on chrome with no caching option and same result. It's possible that among the different versions of IIS and Azure there are different behaviors.

Comment: after the last trial, I also tried by removing the canonical section to test whether the CDN request would come through and it worked, but we need the canonical name enforcement.